# Special character in AJAX request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, special-characters, http-post

I have a problem concerning the input of special characters. Firstly, `+` is considered
as a special character, right? I have a field in my form that needs to be able to contain a `+`. However, when I send it to my PHP script using AJAX and access the variable using `$_POST`, the `+` is not displayed, and therefore, not saved in the database.

Example:

```
// on the JavaScript side
value = +123;
paramPost = "name=abc&value=" + value;
alert("paramPost = " + paramPost);
// Output: parampost = name=abc&value=123
// The + is gone!
// Also, when I change value to a string, the + is still there,
// but when PHP receives it, it's gone.
ajax.doPost(paramPost);
```

```
// on the PHP side
$val = $_POST['value'];
echo "val = $val";
// Output: 123
// The + is no longer there!
```

What can I do to fix this?

I tried this:

```
$val = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

...but it still didn't work.

Comment: please clean up your code and use code tags. is //parampost = name=abc&value=+123 supposed to be commented out? is it relevant?

Comment: i don't know much about php, but isn't there some way you could escape chars?

Comment: hi matchew! thanks man, got the solution already.. i was just writing it out for basis :) im using the encodeURIComponent() and its working fine. thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `+` is redundant on a number; change `+123` to `"+123"`.

If your JavaScript library does not escape that, also do `encodeURIComponent(value)` instead of `value`. So, your fixed code should be:

```
value = "+123";
paramPost = "name=abc&value=" + encodeURIComponent(value); 

// ..

ajax.doPost(paramPost);
```

Comment: hi minitech! thanks a lot! im using the encodeURIComponent() now and it gives out the hex value for +. thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, a leading '+' before a number indicates it is positive. To send the value '+1' as part of a URI query param, you'll need to escape it. The correctly escaped version of '+1' would be:

```
%2B1
```

where %2B is the HEX value for '+'

Comment: hi Rob Raisch!! thanks a lot for that! surely it needs to have the hex value for '+'. thanks man!